# Cordova camera app Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: cordova

How to determine the exact error message instead of `Illegal argument Exception`? I am using a visual studio and avd manager to launch android emulator. The following is the code but when I click the `click` button, the error message is just `ILLEGAL ARGUMENT EXCEPTION`.

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="msg">TESTING</p>
        <button id="btn1">Click</button>

        <img src="" id="img1" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', app.takephoto);
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    takephoto: function () {
        var ops = {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
            //sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            //mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            //encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            //targetWidth: 300,
            //targetHeight: 400
        };
        navigator.camera.getPicture(app.ftw, app.wtf, ops);
    },
    ftw: function (imgURI) {
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = imgURI;
        document.getElementById('img1').src = imgURI;
    },
    wtf: function (msg) {
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = msg;
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

**index.js updated still the same error**

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        document.getElementById('msg').textContent = navigator.camera;
        document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', app.takephoto);
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    takephoto: function () {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(app.onSuccess, app.onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    },

    onSuccess: function (imageURI) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = imageURI;
    },

    onFail: function (message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }


};

app.initialize();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue is because of the incorrect syntax passed for options:

```
<br>
var ops = {
            quality: 50,<br>
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL **(removed comma from here)**<br>
            //sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,<br>
            //mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,<br>
            //encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,<br>
            //targetWidth: 300,<br>
            //targetHeight: 400<br>
        }<br>
```

Please check whether you are facing same behavior now.

Comment: ive changed the index.js but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intitialize cordova camera on device ready, 
    In index.html add this

    <script>
    var destinationType;
    var pictureSource ;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {

        if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {

        }
            pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

        //document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);


    }




   // Now invoke the below function on button click
    function takePicture() {
            var options = {
                    quality: 100,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.CAMERA,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
                    targetWidth: 200,
                    targetHeight: 200,
                    allowEdit : true,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                };
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,options);

            }
        function onSuccess(imageUri) {
            var image = document.getElementById('img1');
            image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + imageUri;



        }
        function onFail(){

         //your error block here
        }

     </script> 


    please try this, it works fine for me.
```

Comment: I still get same error - `ILLEGAL ARGUMENT EXCEPTION`.